# Removing content created by jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, webshop

(according webshop)

I want to add an function remove, where I remove the whole entry inserted using ajax & jquery, but it is not working as I want to.

Using the following code:

```
        $('#div').on('click', '.orderd', function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

function UpdateTotal() {
            ToAddHTML = '<h1>Shopping cart</h1>';
            Totalprice = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < orders.length ; i++) {
                var zoekresultaat = SubMenuItems.filter(function(v) {
                    return v.submenu_id === orders[i];
                })[0];
                Totalprice += parseFloat(searched.price);
                ToAddHTML += '';
            }
            ToAddHTML += ''
            $("#totalen").html(ToAddHTML);
        }
```

This works, but when I console.log the array "orderd items", it still repeats the orderd items. 
So when I click on a different item, the "just-deleted" order is popping up again.

It's kind of hard to explain my current problem, but I hope i've informed enough! For any questions, please ask! ill update my question!

Comment: removing from DOM you do above if you want to delete a variable set it to an empty string

Comment: The jQuery remove function will remove only the matching DOM elements, it has nothing to do with any kind of underlying datasource. You should manually remove the underlying data item from your array.

Comment: What does `(according webshop)` mean?

Comment: Have you tried to create a jsfiddle with a demonstration of the problem? Visit jsfiddle.net

Comment: @j08691 So You have more an idea of what Im talking about

Comment: @AndersLindén I've tried but couldnt reproduce my problem clearly in it.

Comment: @Dagon Could you explain how I can set it in an empty string?

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Is there a jquery function for removing the datasource?

Comment: @RinkeDoeser, could you please post more of your code? We should see your JS data objects, and also your AJAX processing perhaps

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Ive added some extra code

Comment: @ZoltánTamási http://twirre.kweekvijvernoord.nl/calculatorv2/ this is the live website, code is in dutch but I guess you could figure that out

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the ordered id from your array, and recalculate your "basket" when an item is removed.

```
// =======================================================================
// ! Functie maken die de totalen-lijst bijwerkt
// =======================================================================
function WerkTotalenBij() {
    ToeTeVoegenHTML = '<h1>Winkelmandje</h1>';
    Totaalprijs = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < Bestellingen.length ; i++) {
        var zoekresultaat = SubMenuItems.filter(function(v) {
            return v.submenu_id === Bestellingen[i];
        })[0];
        Totaalprijs += parseFloat(zoekresultaat.price);
        // here I put a "data-itemid" attribute to keep a raw reference to the item id
        // this ID can be retrieved in the remove handler
        ToeTeVoegenHTML += '<div class=besteld id=nummer'+Bestellingen[i]+' data-itemid="'+Bestellingen[i]+'">'+'&euro;'+zoekresultaat.price+' '+zoekresultaat.title+'</br>(verwijder)</div><hr>';
    }
    ToeTeVoegenHTML += '<br/>Totale prijs per persoon :<br/> &euro; '+Totaalprijs+'<br/>Minimaal 10 personen<br/> Aantal personen:<input type=text width="10px" /><input type="button" value="Ik ben klaar!">';
    $("#totalen").html(ToeTeVoegenHTML);
}

$('#totalen').on('click', '.besteld', function() {
    var itemID = $(this).data("itemid");
    // remove the item ID from the array
    var index = Bestellingen.indexOf(itemID);
    if (index > -1) {
        Bestellingen.splice(index, 1);
    }        
    $(this).remove();
    // recalculate orders
    WerkTotalenBij();
});
```

But anyway, this is the typical work where you should rather use for example [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) libaray, where you can bind your DOM elements directly to your data, and it's enought to manipulate with your data, the GUI will automatically reflect to the changes. Believe me, it's worth to learn it, you won't regret.